# Can i get the whole chat conversation using botchat.js

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using BotChat.js in my windows form application to get the chat window with this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bot" />
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
        BotChat.App({
            directLine: {secret: direct_line_secret},
            user: {id: 'userid'},
            bot: {id: 'botid'},
            resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is working fine. 
Now i want the whole conversation in my windows form app where i implemented this.

Can i get it? and how ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [DirectLineJs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) library that communicates through the `Direct Line` channel.  The `Direct Line` channel of the Bot Framework only stores messages for a short period (for the sake of stability).  You would need to store and reload the messages in your own code.

`DirectLineJs` provides a mechanism for listening to all incoming and outgoing messages:

```
directLine.activity$
.subscribe(
    activity => console.log("received activity ", activity) //<-- could store messages here
);
```

However, this is client side code (the javascript running in the browser, or win forms web browser control in your case).  Since you're trying to re-load all previous messages for the user when the client starts, you would need to change the library to account for this.  The code (see link above) is open source, so you certainly download it, make the changes, and host the .js on your own server.  `botchat.js` would need to look for the user's previous messages when it starts up, load them, and display them.

Since your bot client is inside of a Win Forms application, another option is to just use the [Direct Line Client](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine) and make your own UI for displaying messages.

---

Note: the current `DirectLineJs` library will start a new conversation every time it loads.  If you're trying to resume a conversation, you need to supply the ConversationId when constructing the client (but like I mentioned earlier, the channel itself only stores these messages for a short time. So you cannot reliably exit a conversation, and reconnect days later expecting to retrieve the conversation history, which is why you have to store the messages yourself):

```
dl = new DirectLine({
    secret: /* SECRET */,
    conversationId: /* the conversationid you stored from previous conversation */
});
```

Comment: thanks @Eric. I have already found the same DirectLineJs link which you have given.. Thanks for your reply... :)

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine and writing your own UI? Instead of using the web chat control?

Comment: There has been some discussion of how to accomplish loading history into the WebChat control here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/365

Answer (score 0):

If anyone trying to get this work along with [Bot Framework WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) component then you will need to disable the WebSocket for this to work properly as shown below.

```js
// Initialize DirectLine connection
botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine
({
     secret: "XXXX",
     conversationId: "XXXX",
     webSocket: false
});
```